# I want to send pdf or html to DocuSign for sign?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to send pdf to DocuSign than point the signature field to auto position it so signer can sign it.
I need to do it by api not manually by going to DocuSign website .

how to do it can you help me where I can I find this on DocuSign api ?

**I don't want to use DocuSign template**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what coding language you may be interested in using, but here is a [code Example for Remote signing](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-request-a-signature-via-email) of either a PDF or HTML in seven different languages, including the original bash script.
You will want to start by getting a developer account and creating an integration key so you can make API calls. Once you have that, you can download the code in https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java (this is Java, you can also find in C#, PHP, Ruby, Node and Python) and run them to see how they work.